# Is GHC able to tail-call optimize IO actions?

Tags: haskell, io, tail-recursion

Will GHC perform tail-call optimization on the following function by default?  The only weird thing about it is that it is recursively defining an IO action, but I don't see why this couldn't be TCO'd.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

consume :: MVar a -> [a] -> IO ()
consume _ [] = return ()
consume store (x:xs) = do putMVar store x
                          consume store xs
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since your code is equivalent to

```
consume store (x:xs) = putMVar store >> consume store xs
```

the call does not actually occur in tail position.  But if you run `ghc -O` and turn on the optimizer, the `-ddump-simpl` option will show you the output of GHC's intermediate code, and it does indeed optimize into a tail-recursive function, which will compile into a loop.

So the answer is GHC won't optimize this by default; you need the `-O` option.

(Experiments done with GHC version 6.10.1.)